# Как обобщить алгоритм работы с данными через EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Мне кажется что логику получения данных, добавления и удаления можно как-то обобщить, так как по сути они все выполняют одно и тоже действие только с разными данными, да еще и таблиц будет достаточно много. Можно ли что-то придумать для данного примера?

```
public interface IDataRepository
{
    IQueryable<Manufacturer> GetManufacturers();
    IQueryable<Product> GetProducts();
    void Add(Product product);
    void Add(Manufacturer manufacturer);
    void Remove(Product product);
    void Remove(Manufacturer manufacturer);
}

public class EFDataRepository : IDataRepository
{
    private readonly WarehouseDbContext _context;

    public EFDataRepository(WarehouseDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<Manufacturer> GetManufacturers() => _context.Manufacturer;

    public IQueryable<Product> GetProducts() => _context.Products;


    public void Add(Manufacturer manufacturer)
    {
        _context.Manufacturer.Add(manufacturer);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Add(Product product)
    {
        _context.Products.Add(product);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Remove(Manufacturer manufacturer)
    {
        _context.Manufacturer.Remove(manufacturer);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Remove(Product product)
    {
        _context.Products.Remove(product);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Придумал вот такое решение:

```
public interface IDataRepository
{
    void Add<T>(T entity) where T : class;
    void Remove<T> (T entity) where T : class;
    IQueryable<T> GetData<T>() where T : class;
}

public class EFDataRepository : IDataRepository
{
    private readonly WarehouseDbContext _context;
    public EFDataRepository(WarehouseDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public void Add<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    public void Remove<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    public IQueryable<T> GetData<T>() where T : class => _context.Set<T>();
}
```

Comment: Собственно, так обычно и делаются репозитории.